# Computing derivative of logarithm of a specific matrix function.

Tags: derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to compute equation $(5.23)$ from [here](http://robotics.caltech.edu/wiki/images/d/d1/RasumussenWilliamsBook.pdf#page=143) where I replaced the variable $\hat{f}$ by $x$ for ease of notation.

By definition $B(x) := I + W(x)^{1/2}KW(x)^{1/2}$ with $K$ and $W$ symmetric matrices. I would like to show that $$(log |B|)'(x)=tr\left[((K^{-1}+W(x))^{-1}W'(x)\right]$$ where $|\cdot|$ is the determinant of a matrix.

I know that $ (log(B(x)))' = tr(B(x)^{-1}B'(x) $ and using the product rule I can get $$B'(x)=\frac{1}{2}W(x)^{-1/2}W'(x)KW(x)^{1/2}+W(x)^{1/2}K\frac{1}{2}W(x)^{-1/2}W'(x).$$ Now if I can show that the term $B^{-1}=(K^{-1}+W(x))^{-1}$ (is it true though and how to prove it?) I could use that inside the trace, if every matrix is symmetric we can permute them anyway we like and I would have
$(log |B|)'(x) = tr\left[K^{-1}+W(x))^{-1}KW'(x)\right]$ and I would have a $K$ too much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Supposing that $W(x)^{1/2}$ is invertible, we have
$B(x) = I + W(x)^{1/2}KW(x)^{1/2}= W(x)^{1/2}(I+KW(x))W(x)^{-1/2}$,
so $|B|=|I+KW(x)| = |K||K^{-1}+W(x)|$. Then just apply what you know. (It also works for non-invertible $W$'s, where one needs to use the identity $|I+XY|=|I+YX|$.)